# Creating a "joins" query 2 associations up

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a situation where a `CourseSession` belongs to a `Course`, which belongs to a `Program`. In my controller I'd like to get the name of the program from the CourseSession. I've been looking around and have been seeing a lot of people suggest using the `joins` method. Unfortunately for me this didn't work in my case. I get this error:

```
Can't join 'CourseSession' to association named 'program'; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
@sessions = if params[:program]
  CourseSession.joins(:course).joins(:program).where("program.name = params[:program]")
else
  CourseSession.all
end
```

---

```
class Program < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courses, dependent: :nullify
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sessions, class_name: "CourseSession", inverse_of: :course, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :program
end

class CourseSession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `CourseSession.joins(:course).joins(:program)` (i.e. chaining joins), you're just joining `course_sessions` table with `courses` table and `programs` table hence the error.

What you've asked for can be achieved using the following syntax:

```
CourseSession.joins(course: :program)
```

Here, `courses` and `programs` table are inner joined and `course_sessions` and `courses` table are inner joined.

Second issue is in your `where` method. The table names are plural by convention so you should be using `programs.name` instead of `program.name`. Try the following instead:

```
CourseSession.joins(course: :program).where("programs.name = ?", params[:program])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still a little new to querying so I must ask; do I take any performance hits when writing something that travels up the association chain? If so would you happen to have any suggestions?

Comment: As long as you have index on `courses.program_id` and `course_sessions.course_id`, you should be good. This is not a report I imagine so I think you are safe.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. What do you mean by "report"?

Comment: Uh oh, how do I explain reports. I defer to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+software+report).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what your trying to do. Your code suggests you want:

- `CourseSessions` associated with the `Program` if `params[:program]` is present, and
- All `CourseSessions` if `params[:program]` is not present.

In which case I believe you'd do something like:

```
@sessions = if params[:program]
  CourseSession.where(course: Course.where(program: Program.find_by(name: params[:program])))
else
  CourseSession.all
end
```